# How to setup a cron job in mac to run a simple backup.sh script

Tags: bash, macos, cron

It seems that I am too dumb to set up a cron job on my mac Catalina 10.15.7 or I am doing something extremely wrong.

I have written a simple backup script that creates a folder with a timestamp and then copies another folder into the new one and afterwards send it to a remote server using scp. All saved in the backupScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#######
# Create date variable. I want the date format to look like this.
#######
d=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')

#######
# Make directory in  this backup folder to send to the server.
#######
mkdir /Users/my-name/Documents/Backup/_$d

#######
# Copy files into newly created directory.
#######
cp -R /Users/my-name/Documents/path/to/important/file /Users/my-name/Documents/Backup/_$d

#######
# Copy folder with scp and move it to new location on my server.
#######
scp -r -i /Users/my-name/.ssh/id_rsa /Users/my-name/Documents/Backup/_$d user@255.255.255.255:path/to/backup/dir/on/server
```

When I execute the script manually it works flawless and does everything it is supposed to do in the right order and everything. However, I don't have the time to always manually run the scrip (or I simply forget about it when I am in a hurry).

So I wanted to create a cron job for this. The crontab -l command shows me that the crontab has been made but it won't execute the script. So maybe I am doing it wrong or give it the wrong commands to execute.

Here is what I did so far, in order to get the script to run:

1. use `crontab -e`
2. In the editor i wrote the folloging `*/5 * * * * cd /Users/my-name/Documents/Backup && ./backupScript.sh`
3. Saved the editor using `:wq`
4. Check if the tab has been created using `crontab -l`

Am I doing something wrong? Or can't I just setup cron jobs on mac whatsoever?
Any help you can provide is very very welcomed. I am really going crazy over this here.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: How did you execute the script manually?

Comment: Did you do `chmod 755 backupScript.sh`?

Comment: @Roadowl Thanks for the advice, my friend. I found the problem already. And yes, I did a chmod 755 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something wrong with the code itself. I changed the crontab into the following line:

`*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /Users/my-name/Documents/Backup/backupScript.sh`

And gave the cron app permission to write on the disk. Afterwards it worked like a charm.